# Как уменьшить размер файла Blob?

Tags: canvas, blob, crop

Мне даётся картинка, я её обрезаю с помощью imageCrop, дальше через canvas создаю blob файл для передачи его на бек, однако конечный файл весит больше первоначального в 10 раз. Как мне уменьшить размер конечного файла, чтоб он не превышал первоначальный?

Comment: Ну например передавать как есть бинарным файлом, а не кодировать в BASE64 (хотя все равно не понятно, откуда 10 раз могло взяться, где-то в 2-3 раза могло увеличиться при BASE64)

Comment: [Предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1552401) был закрыт за отсутствие релевантного кода, сейчас и этот опять закроют